# How to execute bash command time not /usr/bin/time via subprocess module?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to create a small script for doing some benchmarking for me. I'm using `subprocess.Popen` to execute the time command. A sample of the code:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

command = shlex.split("time thing_im_benchmarking")
p = subprocess.Popen(command)
p.wait()
```

The output I get is

> 2.58user 0.04system 0:02.83elapsed 92%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 11568maxresident)k
>   0inputs+0outputs (0major+791minor)pagefaults 0swaps

What I really wanted was

```
real    0m3.048s
user    0m2.784s
sys 0m0.040s
```

How do I get Popen to execute the built-in bash command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `shell=True` to `subprocess.Popen()`

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is kind of late, but a way to get a standardized output for the time-program is by using the flag -p. This will get you a time output according to the POSIX 2 standard. This helped me a lot when I tried to evaluate my timings using a program automatically collecting them.